# Let $V$ be a vector space and $u,v∈V$. Prove {$u,v$} is linearly independent if and only if {$u+v,u-v$} is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $V$ be a vector space and $u,v∈V$. Prove {$u,v$} is linearly independent if and only if{$u+v,u-v$} is linearly independent.

consider $(c+d)u+(c-d)v=0$.

we obtain $cu+du+cv-dv=c(u+v)+d(u-v)=0$ but because $u+v,u-v$ are linearly independent $c=d=0$. it follows that $c-d=0$ and $c+d=0$. so $u,v$ are linearly independent.

Now for the other directions..

consider $c(u+v)+d(u-v)=0$.

we obtain $cu+cv+du-dv=(c+d)u+(c-d)v=0$ but because $u,v$ are linearly independent $c+d=0$ and $c-d=0$. therefore, $c=d=0$ and $u+v,u-v$ are linearly independent. q.e.d.

Is this  a valid proof? For the first direction, is starting with $(c+d)u+(c-d)v=0$ allowed?

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal to start with $(c+d)u+(c-d)v=0$. There's an implicit assumption here that any linear combination $au + bv$ can be expressed in the form $(c + d)u + (c - d)v$. Or, to put it another way, the map $(c, d) \mapsto (c + d, c - d)$ is surjective. If I, as a reader, wanted proof that $2u + 3v \neq 0$, I would then have to figure out which values of $c$ and $d$ would make $(c + d)u + (c - d)v = 2u + 3v$, or just trust that it could be done.

Now, the implicit assumption turns out to be totally correct, but that's beside the point. The proof should either prove this assumption explicitly, or should tackle this direction a different way.

Inverting the map $(c, d) \mapsto (c + d, c - d)$ actually gives us a good way forward here. If we have $(c + d, c - d) = (a, b)$, then
\begin{align*}
c + d &= a \\
c - d &= b.
\end{align*}
Adding the equations, we get $2c = a + b$, and subtracting, we get $2d = a - b$. So, the inverse map is
$$(a, b) \mapsto \left(\frac{a + b}{2}, \frac{a - b}{2}\right).$$
So, if my powers of intuition are correct, then
$$au + bv = \frac{a + b}{2}(u + v) + \frac{a - b}{2}(u - v).$$
Try using the above fact to finish your proof.

Comment: I think I understand your point, but do you mean to say the map $(c+d, c-d) \mapsto (a, b)$ is surjective instead of "the map $(c, d) \mapsto (c + d, c - d)$ is surjective?"

Comment: If i prove this fact, then could I consider the proof complete?

Comment: @not_tiger No, I did mean what I wrote. Indeed, $(a, b) \mapsto (c + d, c - d)$ is not really a sensible function definition, as it is not clear what relationship $a$ and $b$ have to $c$ and $d$. I would use the last line of my answer in your proof. Start with "Suppose $au + bv = 0$. Then $\frac{a + b}{2}(u + v) + \frac{a - b}{2}(u - v) = 0$..." What does the linear independence of $\{u + v, u - v\}$ tell you?

Comment: Im confused because I think that we need to show any a,b can be represented by c+d, c-d respectively: $(c+d,c−d)↦(a,b)$ where a,b are the scalars that make the linear combination of the vectors equal to 0. doesn't the surjectivity of  $(c,d)↦(c+d,c−d)$ hold immediately? am I making the thing I am confused about clear to you?

Comment: I think so? It might be hard for me to explain. I think I'm confusing things by failing to give the function a name. Let's call this function $f$, i.e. $f(c, d) = (c + d, c - d)$. It's a perfectly well-defined function from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to $\Bbb{R}^2$. In order to test for surjectivity, we need to show that, given any $(a, b) \in \Bbb{R}^2$, the equation $f(c, d) = (a, b)$ has a solution for $(c, d)$. I really wouldn't worry too much about it though. My comment about this map being surjective was really just motivation to construct the last equality in my answer.